# What is the difference between "py[cod]" and "pyc" in .gitignore notation?

Tags: python, git

What is the difference (if any) between ".pyc" and ".py[cod]" notation in ignoring files.  I am noticing I have both on my git ignore file. Thanks

Comment: @CarlNorum: The OP is not asking about what those extensions mean, just if the pattern `.py[cod]` covers ignoring `.pyc` already. It's a `git` question, not a Python question.

Comment: It says "What is the difference (if any) between .pyc and .py[cod] files".

Comment: It's ambiguous. It appears to ask about the difference between the .py{c,o,d} file extensions, but may really be a Git question about gitignore patterns, since that sparked the question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are safe to remove the `.pyc` entry from your `.gitignore`, since `.py[cod]` will cover it. The square brackets are for matching any one of the characters, so it matches `.pyc`, `.pyo` and `.pyd`.

Since they are all generated from the `.py` source, they should not be stored in source control.

Comment: .pyd files are windows dlls and are not generated by .py files. They are typically compiled from C or C++ source and should be ignored by git much like generated .exe are ignored. If, however, somebody decided to check .pyd files into the repo, you would want to remove the [d] from the ignore file.

Comment: so .pyd files are Python file generated from C or C++ ?

Comment: The source for a `.pyd` module may be written in any language, but the `.pyd` file itself is a binary file containing executable code.